# Как в jsoup элементы поменять местами?

Tags: android, xml, jsoup, xmlparser, android-xml

К примеру есть у меня такая структура

```
<Element1>Text1</Element1>
<Element2>Text2</Element2>
```

Так вот как мне поднять второй элемент чтоб он находился над первым ?

Comment: Ну... Создать новые элементы в нужном порядке на основе имеющихся. Удалить старые, вместо них поместить новые. Кодом не помогу - не помню как оно там, но так работать будет.

Comment: вообще - странно, как по мне, использовать JSOUP для редактирования HTML... Напишите лучше, зачем вам это надо, я думаю, есть более простой способ...

Comment: @metalurgus Я делаю сохранение файлов через xml, и для считывания и редактирования использую jsoup, у меня есть массив который я сохраняю через цикл в xml, иногда надо его редактировать к примеру изменить название, тогда я нахожу данный элемент через jsoup удаляю его и добавляю новый элемент с новым названием, и перезаписываю xml. Но этот самый элемент он добавляется внизу списка, а хотелось бы чтоб он оставался на том же месте где и старый элемент. Надеюсь нормально пояснил :D

Comment: @Fasd, изменить имя тэга просто, ничего удалять не надо: `element.tagName("newTagName");`

Comment: Ещё можно добавить к-л элемент спереди/сзади заданного `Element.prependElement(String tag)` и `Element.appendElement(String tag)` соответственно